# Error: Cannot open xxx.msg in Outlook Drag and Drop add in

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating add-in for outlook. In which I have created Drag and Drop user control.
In that when I drag drop mails, Some mail are fetched and provide proper information but in some of the mails in Inbox gives me the Error Like:

[image]

I am using following code to get Information of the dragged mails:

```
private void DragNDropArea_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //wrap standard IDataObject in OutlookDataObject
    OutlookDataObject dataObject = new OutlookDataObject(e.Data);

    //get the names and data streams of the files dropped
    string[] filenames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");
    MemoryStream[] filestreams = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");

    this.label2.Text += "Files:\n";
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filenames.Length; fileIndex++)
    {
        try
        {
            //use the fileindex to get the name and data stream
            string filename = filenames[fileIndex];
            MemoryStream filestream = filestreams[fileIndex];
            this.label2.Text += "    " + filename + "\n";

            Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._NameSpace nameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon(null, null, false, false);
            Outlook.Folder folder = (Outlook.Folder)app.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            //From this it gives me mentioned error...
            Outlook.MailItem msg = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItemFromTemplate(filename, folder);
            string sender1 = msg.SenderEmailAddress;

            MessageBox.Show("Sender: \n" + msg.Sender.Name + "\n" + msg.Sender.Address);
            MessageBox.Show("Message Body: \n" + msg.Body);
            MessageBox.Show("Total Attachments: " + msg.Attachments.Count);
            for (int i = 1; i <= msg.Attachments.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Attachment " + i + " :" + msg.Attachments[i].FileName);
                msg.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile("C:\\TestFileSave\\" + msg.Attachments[i].FileName);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured In getting Mail info..: \n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

And when I drag mails from the folders which I have created in the Inbox folder it gives me the same error for every mails which are dragged.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is STG_E_FILENOTFOUND.

I am not sure how your code could have ever worked: you are passing just the file name (it does not have path) that Outlook would have used to name it (e.g. "My Subject.msg") if you dragged the mesage to Windows Explorer. You need to save the memory stream (filestream in your code above) to an actual file. The file name does not make any difference.

Comment: Hey, If you want u can try that code. I am able to get mail info using above code. But in some mails it gives me error. The reason that i got mail info is that filename object contains the .msg file name and the other object contains the Inbox folder info. So that I am able to get Mail info on drag and drop.

Comment: What is the exact value of the filename variable when you call CreateItemFromTemplate?

Comment: It is the .msg file's name. e.g. "myMailFile.msg"

Comment: So how can CreateItemFromTemplate possibly open it unless you have an MSG file with that file name in the current directory or somewhere along the PATH? Do save the stream to a file and pass the fully qualified file name to CreateItemFromTemplate.

Comment: If I save that stream to some file, I have to save that file to my local drive. That I don't want to do.!

Comment: CreateItemFromTemplate only works with existing files. There is no way around that.

Comment: Yes I see that it works only with existing files. That is why it gives me some file with my above code. But it do not works for every files. Is there any other way that u know for using drag and drop control in Outlook addin.

Comment: If you immediately reopen the message, why do you need to save it to begin with? To drag a message from Outlook, you need to select it first, which means Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection collection will have the messages being dragged.

Comment: Because when I drag and drop the message, I get that message in a stream and I have to convert that stream to MailItem object. For that I use above code, And other code also that can save that mail to .msg file to my local drive. And saving to my local drive gives me error that file is not accessible. so that I am using this approach.

Comment: Why is the file not accessible? What is your code that raises the error when you process selected messages in Outlook?